# Forcing in Homotopy Type Theory

Tags: forcing, homotopy-type-theory, infinity-topos-theory, lo.logic, type-theory

I apologize if this question doesn't make any sense. I'll just go ahead and delete it if that's the case.  But the question is just the title.  Is there a notion of forcing in homotopy type theory? Presumably we do homotopy type theory in some $(\infty,1)$-topos, so we can axiomatize the notions accordingly? Does anyone know of a reference for this kind of thing if it does exist or makes sense?

Thanks

Comment: and, while we are at it, what could it be used for?

Comment: Probably improving the efficiency of the internal combustion engine.

Comment: Can you add the tag lo.logic ? Thanks! (Later on, there will perhaps be a need for a HoTT tag, but in the meantime I think adding logic as a tag to questions like this will help, as the people interested in HoTT aren't necessarily interested in set theory, nor abstract homotopy or infinity-topos theory outside of the type-theoretic context.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In as far as we regard [forcing](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/forcing) as forming [internal sheaves](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal%20sheaf), the question is asking how to say "internal category of sheaves" in [homotopy type theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy%20type%20theory).

It is expected that this works in directed analogy with the situation in ordinary type theory by considering [internal sites](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal%20site), except that there is a technical problem currently not fully solved: in homotoy type theory an internal category is necessarily an [internal (infinity,1)-category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal%20%28infinity,1%29-category) and in order to say this one needs to be able to say "(semi-)[simplicial object](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial%20object%20in%20an%20%28infinity,1%29-category) in the homotopy type theory". This might seem immediate, but is a little subtle, due to the infinite tower of higher coherences involved. For *truncated* internal categories one might proceed "by hand" as indicated [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+object+in+an+%28infinity%2C1%29-category#HomotopyTypeTheoryFormulation). A general formalization has recently been proposed by Voevodsky -- see the webpage *[UF-IAS-2012 -- Semi-simplicial types](http://uf-ias-2012.wikispaces.com/Semi-simplicial+types)* -- but this definition does not in fact at the moment work in homotopy type theory. (Last I heard was that Voevodsky had been thinking about *changing* homotopy type theory itself to make this work. But this is second-hand information only, we need to wait for one of the IAS-HoTT fellows to see this here and give us first-order news on this.)

However, that all said, there is something else which one can do and which *does* work: if an $\infty$-topos is equipped with a notion of (formally) *étale morphisms*, then one can speak about internal sheaves over the canonical internal site of any object without explicitly considering the internal site itself: the "petit (infintiy,1)-topos" of sheaves on a given object $X \in \mathbf{H}$ is the full sub-(oo,1)-category of the slice over $X$ on the (formally) étale maps

It may seem surprising on first sight, but this can be saiD in homotopy type theory and it can be said naturally and elegantly:

For this we simply add the axioms of *differential [cohesive homotopy type theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cohesive%20homotopy%20type%20theory)* to plain homotopy type theory. This means that we declare there to be two adjoint triples of idempotent (co)monadic [modalities](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/modal%20type%20theory) called

[shape modality](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/shape%20modality) $\dashv$ [flat modality](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/flat%20modality) $\dashv$ [sharp modality](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sharp%20modality)

and

[reduction modality](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reduction%20modality) $\dashv$ [infinitesimal shape modality](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/infinitesimal+shape+modality) $\dashv$ [infinitesimal flat modality](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/infinitesimal+flat+modality) .

Using this we say: a function is formally étale if its naturality square of the unit of the "infinitesimal shape modality" is a homotopy pullback square. Then we have available in the homotopy type theory the sub-slice over any $X$ on those maps that are formally étale. This is internally the $\infty$-topos of $\infty$-stacks over $X$, hence the "forcing of $X$" in terms of the standard interpretation of forcing as passing to sheaves.

What I just indicated is discussed in detail in section 3.10.4 and 3.10.7 of the notes

*Differential cohomology in a cohesive $\infty$-topos*

( http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/differential+cohomology+in+a+cohesive+topos )

For more details on the above axioms of cohesive homotopy type theory see the first section of my article with Mike Shulman:

*Quantum gauge field theory in Cohesive homotopy type theory*

( http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/Quantum+gauge+field+theory+in+Cohesive+homotopy+type+theory )

Comment: Wow thanks very much Urs. I probably should have brought this up on the nForum to avoid questions of "usefulness" but you found it anyway! As usual, there's quite a bit to digest here, but I very much appreciate you taking the question seriously.  I suspected that this question was not fully resolved. Exciting!

Comment: Not to say that the people at nForum only consider useless stuff! =P

Comment: Nice summary, Urs.  I don't know of any further developments on the semisimplicial objects front, except that Hugo Herbelin has attacked it from a similar but different direction to Voevodsky and come quite close; he might even have succeeded by now.  It's not entirely clear to me whether the problem is merely a (terrifically difficult) bookkeeping one, or something more basic.

Comment: One other thing which I might add is that for a very simple class of cases, there is an alternative approach: http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3253

Comment: Jon, we have no use for things that have no use. And if it has no use, you cannot force it.

Comment: @Urs, you're not even talking about math and I'm still confused.

Comment: @Jon, sorry, I was just joking. Shouldn't do that.

Comment: @Urs, haha, no it's great. People are too serious on here anyway.